# How do we calculate the period times based on user's input of start-time and end-time for the day in angular?

Tags: angular, timepicker, calculation, period, timetable

I'm setting up a timetable project for school management. I wanted to get the start time and end time of the day by a school admin for which I'm using a modal dialog.[image] The above image holds only static period times for 9 different periods with equal interval of time. 
[image]The above is the modal which i'm using to get the desired times for each factors in the timetable period duration.

Say there are 9 periods in a day, I wanted the time to be broken down into 9 slots based on the user's start and end time of the day and along with the user's period duration.

I haven't tried any code as i didn't get a clear idea of how i'm gonna do that. I have added some screenshots though.

Periods needs to be calculated based on the user's period duration, When 9 periods are allotted for the day, it should automatically be broken down in to 9 different time slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below given code to divide given time range in 9 equal parts:

```
    let arr = [];
    let dt1 = new Date().setHours(9, 45, 0); // this would be given by user as input
    let dt2 = new Date().setHours(16, 30, 0);// this would be given by user as input
    const interval = (dt2-dt1)/9;
    for (let i=0; i<9; i++) {
        const period = {
            start: new Date(dt1+(i*interval)),
            end: new Date(dt1+((i+1)*interval))
        }
        arr.push(period);
     }
```

You can loop through array and get the start end time of each slot:

```
arr.forEach((slot, index) => {
    // index 0 will be first slot and last index will be last one
    console.log(`Slot start: ${slot.start}`);
    console.log(`Slot end: ${slot.end}`);
})
```

Comment: Okay but how do we display the broken times in the right slot ? Please check my image where i've given static time intervals.

Comment: The array will contain all the slots in ascending order. First array item will be first slot, then second and so on.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for me ?

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer. Is there a way to get time dynamically with a timepicker instead of setting the time by default

Comment: Here's the edited stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-time-picker?embed=1